# Finding the distance between two moving objects

Tags: vectors, physics

In this case there is a missile whose initial position is $A(30,40)$ with a velocity of $[50,30]$ and an asteroid whose initial position is $B(400,250)$ with a velocity of $[-20,-30]$. The position of each object is given by the equations $ \ a = [30,40] + t[50, 30] \ $ and $ \ b = [400,250] + t[-20,-30] \ $.

I need to explain why distance between these two at any time t is given by the equation $$d^2 \  = \  181000 \  - \ 77000 \ t \  +  \ 8500\ t^2 \ \ . $$ I know that the first term $18100$ is the distance between the two initial positions and that the final term is the distance traveled for each object but, what is the middle term?

Comment: "Middle term"? What does that mean?  What is the domain of $\;t\;$ ? Perhaps you mean the vaule of the distance when $\;t\;$ is at the middle of its domain?

Comment: I have corrected a typo in your expression for the positive of $ \ a \ $ and the omission of the $ \  t  \ $ in the last term of your "distance-squared" function.  The second _and_ third terms are  the result of applying   the distance formula:  the squared-distance is a quadratic function. (The third term is _not_ the "distance traveled for each object".) All three terms would appear even if the two objects were heading straight for one another.

Comment: The middle term consists of velocity by time, while the last term is acceleration by time.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: Acceleration by "time squared".

Comment: @Alexm. I missed that. Thanks

Comment: How would it represent "acceleration" when: (1) this is a distance-_squared_ function and not simply distance; and (2) the quadratic term will appear even if you have two objects moving along the same line at _constant_ velocities?

Comment: I am simply confused because I have to explain why this equation is equal to $d^2$ and I don't see how it is.

Comment: @Joanpemo No I mean algebraically the middle term as in $-77000t$. The domain of $t$ is any given time in seconds.

Comment: @ayNONE That really didn't help me to understand better... That "the middle term as in $\;-77000t\;$" makes no sense to me at all... Could it be you mean **the linear term*, i.e.: the monomial where the first power of $\;t\;$ appears? And if you really do mean this, why are you asking then? Haven't you written $\;-77000t\;$ ? What is then the question???

Comment: @Joanpemo I have not written this I have been asked to explain why distance squared is equivalent to the above equation. I am trying to figure out how the people who wrote this assignment came to this equation. I can see that the first algebraic term (and yes that is the correct word for it) is the distance between the initial positions squared and that the last term the second is the distance of the first vector minus the second. However I cannot fathom how $-77000t$ came about at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated by @N.S.JOHN the terms specify the initial position, velocity with which they come together (since there's a negative sign) and at last the acceleration at which them come apart (since it's a positive sign).

To find those coeffiecients (181000, -77000, 8500) you'll need to do some vector algebra.

Let's assume that $a$ it's a vector-valued function of time that represents the movement of the missile so $\vec{a}(t) = [30, 40] + t[50,30]$. Let's represent the meteor movement $b$ in the same manner $\vec{b}(t) = [400, 250] + t[-20, -30]$. Since they are vectors in the $R^2$ vector space we can decompose each vector in their constituents components:

$\vec{a}(t) = a_x + a_y$ in which $a_x(t) = 30 + 50t$ and $a_y(t) = 40 + 30t$  corresponds to the horizontal and vertical movements of the missil respectively.

The same goes for the meteor:

$\vec{b}(t) = b_x + b_y$ in which $b_x(t) = 400 + 250t$ and $b_y(t) = -20 -30t$  corresponds to the horizontal and vertical movements of the meteor respectively.

Now we have all the pieces we need to measure the distance between both as a function of time:

$d(\vec{a}(t), \vec{b}(t)) = \sqrt{(a_x - b_x)^2 + (a_y - b_y)^2}$

$d^2(\vec{a}(t), \vec{b}(t)) = (a_x - b_x)^2 + (a_y - b_y)^2$

$d^2(\vec{a}(t), \vec{b}(t)) = (30 + 50t - (400 - 20t))^2 + (40 + 30t - (250 - 30t))^2$

$d^2(\vec{a}(t), \vec{b}(t)) = (370 - 70t)^2 + (210 - 60t)^2$

$d^2(\vec{a}(t), \vec{b}(t)) = 370^2 + 210^2 - 2 \times 370 \times 70t - 2 \times 210\times 60t + 70^2t^2 + 60^2t^2$

and finally:

$d^2(\vec{a}(t), \vec{b}(t)) = 181000 - 77000t + 8500t^2$

this you can simply (with some abuse of notation) to:

$d^2 = 181000 - 77000t + 8500t^2$